# (MKMapItem iOS10) marker disappear on map when add "name"

Tags: swift, ios10, mkmapitem

this code

```
        let latitude:CLLocationDegrees =  location.coordinate.latitude
        let longitude:CLLocationDegrees =  location.coordinate.longitude
        let coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)
        let placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinates, addressDictionary: nil)
        let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)
        mapItem.name = location.address
        mapItem.openInMaps(launchOptions: nil)
```

on iOS10 when add mapItem.name = location.address
Marker will disappear on map when the map already has same marker.
but this problem not show on iOS9.

Comment: I also have this problem in iOS 10 only. Did you find a workaround?